# Is it possible to filter by namespace in XPath?

Tags: c#, wcf, xpath, filter, routes

I have a series of services and I want to give them each different prefixes for their unique namespaces.

Now all I've left to do is to sort according to namespace appearing on the SOAP.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:nil="http://NilooSoft.com">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <nil:ApplicantGetByForeignId>

          </nil:ApplicantGetByForeignId>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

And by this I mean simply to find out whether this message contains a node that has the prefix nil (or other prefixes for my other services and so on).
I could name services to cards, dir, interface and so forth and then filter by that content. Is this possible, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to use XPath to find element in certain namespace. This can be done using `namespace-uri()` function like so :

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://NilooSoft.com']
```

The URI address referenced by the namespace prefix is more meaningful in XML than the prefix it self, so it makes more sense to filter element by URI address as in the above example. But, if you somehow want to filter by the namespace prefix instead, you can try this way :

```
//*[starts-with(name(),'nil:')]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the advice, it does help on its own, but I need something a little more specific; I want to check whether such a node exists to begin with and return boolean, will using boolean() around your solution work here?

Comment: @Midnight_Blaze sure it will : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/d58f564ad65a495f2f2c6331927e928d (click test button to run the demo)